# How to create new vertices to connect edges?

Tags: vertices, edges

I've just started to make my first donut in Blender and accidentally deleted my vertices. Now I cannot connect my edges and there is a whole in a mesh.

[image]

Comment: Pleae share your file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it. Then I can show you how to reconnect it without having to create a new model myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, just create a `Loop Cut` (<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> [macOS], <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> [win]) on the surfaces on which you accidently deleted your vertices and merge them (in your case probably only one, according to your screenshot) afterwards by pressing <kbd>M</kbd>.

Comment: I think he'd still have to merge verts after doing that.

Comment: y, thx, i edited my answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!!